# Re-applying after refused UK visit visa

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

My mother and I recently both got visit visa refusal, although we have visited the UK 6-7 times and never got any refusal.

The refusal point for my mum was that:

> in your previous application you have stated that you intend to stay
>   in UK for a period of one month, however you remained in the UK for
>   more than 4 months and you have not mentioned the reason why you
>   stayed for this long period.

The reason we stayed there for more than the intended period was that my brother was buying property and he wanted my mum and dad to receive the keys and step in the house first. They left the UK one week after he got the house keys and documents etc. Also, the EID festivals fell in the same dates, which we wanted to celebrate together.

My refusal point was that, in addition to the above mentioned point of length of stay, I provided employment letter and salary slips but my bank statement does not show the monthly salary. My company pays cash if the salary is less than Rupees 50,000/- so it's not showing in my bank statement.

How can I prove my employment? Can I add some office pictures, a letter from my employer that they are paying my in cash, pictures of some conferences and training I participate in? Any other ideas?

Comment: One question: when you said, in your previous application, that you would only stay for 1 month, was that true at that time? In other words, were you planning to spend 4 months from the beginning, or did the plans simply change once you were already in the UK?

Comment: yes that was true at that time. The property buying took time and got delayed. My brother has all the emails from the seller, that shows the delay was natural.